# $\sigma-$algebra , inverse function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inverse

Is a $\sigma-$algebra a set that contains all the subsets of a set?

In my lecture notes there isthe following:

$$f(x)=\sin x \\ f^{-1}\left (\left [\frac{1}{2}, 1\right ]\right )=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \left [2k \pi +\frac{\pi }{6}, 2k \pi+\frac{5 \pi}{6} \right ]$$

To calculate this we want to find the values of $x$ so that $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=1$ or not ???

But why is at both limits of the interval $\frac{\pi}{6}$ ???

Shouldn't it also be $\frac{\pi}{2}$ ???

**Edit:**

$$\sin x \leq 1 \Rightarrow x \leq 2k \pi+\frac{\pi}{2} \text{ AND } x \leq 2k \pi -\frac{\pi}{2}=2k\pi +\frac{3\pi}{2}$$

$$\sin x \geq \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow x \geq 2k \pi+\frac{\pi}{6} \text{ AND } x \geq 2k\pi -\frac{\pi}{6}=2k \pi+\frac{11\pi}{6}$$

Therefore, we get the following:

[image]

So how do we get this interval???

Comment: No in general. Otherwise it is called the power set. $\sigma$-algebra is a subset of the power set. And the sinesoid goes up and down, so it should be $\pi/6$ and $5\pi/6$.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) for definition of $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 0):

A $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$
  of $\Omega$
  is a part of $\mathcal{P}\left(\Omega\right)$
  such that $\emptyset\in\mathcal{F}$
 , $\mathcal{F}$
  is stable by finite intersections and also stable by countable unions.

Now,$$\sin^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]=\bigcup_{k=0}^{+\infty}\left[\frac{\pi}{6}+k2\pi,\frac{5\pi}{6}+k2\pi\right]$$
 because for any $k\geq0$
 , if $$x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{6}+k2\pi,\frac{5\pi}{6}+k2\pi\right],$$
 then $$\sin\left(x\right)\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]
 .$$

Let us consider the case $k=0$.
When $\frac{\pi}{6}\leq x<\frac{\pi}{2},$ we have $\frac{1}{2}\leq\sin\left(x\right)<1$
  and $\sin$
  is stricly increasing on this interval (since $\cos>0$
  here). After, we have clearly $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right].$
But now, consider $\frac{\pi}{2}<x\leq\frac{5\pi}{6}$
  : here $\sin$
  is stricly decreasing (since $\cos<0$
  here), and ranges from $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$
  to $\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$ We must not forget these possible values for $x$.
 [image]

Comment: How did you find $$\left [ \frac{\pi}{6}+k 2 \pi, \frac{\pi}{2}+k\frac{5 \pi}{6} \right ]$$ although $\sin x =1$ when $x=2k \pi +\frac{\pi}{2}$ ???

Comment: Also I have added something at my question. Please look at it! @Nicolas

Comment: How did you find at $\frac{\pi}{2}+k \frac{5 \pi}{6}$ the term $\frac{5 \pi}{6}$ ???

Comment: @Nicolas You have a typo. $\left [2k \pi +\frac{\pi }{6}, 2k \pi+\frac{5 \pi}{6} \right ]$

Comment: You say that we consider that $x$ is in an interval and conclude that $\sin x$ is in $[1/2, 1]$. But we have that $\sin x$ is in $[1/2, 1]$ and we want to find for which values of $x$ it stands. How can we find the interval of $x$ without using a graph???

Comment: Thank you  Axoren, fixed now!
user159870, you are right, we need a double inclusion to prove the equality of sets. But I specified that $sin$ where strictly monotonous on some intervals, i.e. is bijective. All the values that belong to the intervals $\left[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2}\right[$ and $\left]\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right]$ are therefore counted.